# Getting an error when i am changing my folder location

Tags: c#, string, linq, substring

i am getting an error when i am changed my location to my network location. It only happened for one folder. My error is `index and length must refer to location with in sub-string`.

Error:

> [image]

Code snippet:

```
private void list()
 {
 List<string> stFileNames = new List<string>();
        stFileNames.AddRange(arrRelease);
        foreach (var r in arrDraft)
        {
            if (stFileNames.FindAll(m => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(m).ToUpper().Substring(0, 8).Equals(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(r).ToUpper().Substring(0, 8))).Count == 0)
       //getting error in the above line.. Only when i am giving to one particular location
        /which i need then that time i am getting this error.
                stFileNames.Add(r);
        }

        dt.Columns.Add("Drawing Number");
        dt.Columns.Add("Drawing Path");
        dt.Columns.Add("Draft Path");
        dt.Columns.Add("Release Path");
        dt.Columns.Add("Error");
        dt.Columns.Add("Archive");

        List<FileDetails> lst = new List<FileDetails>();
        //matching files according to the realse folder
        foreach (string f in stFileNames)
        {
            Finder finder = new Finder(Path.GetFileName(f).Substring(0, 8));
            string abc = Array.Find(arrDraft, finder.Match);
            string def = Array.Find(arrRelease, finder.Match);
            string cdf = Array.Find(arrDrawing, finder.Match);
            //matching file in the location Drawing
            string ghi = Array.Find(arrArchive, finder.Match);
            //matching file in the location Archieve
            dt.Rows.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f), cdf, abc, def, String.Empty, ghi);
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

Comment: @alykins `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(m).ToUpper().Substring(0, 8).Equals(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(r).ToUpper().Substring(0, 8))).Count == 0)`

Comment: Your file name is not 8 char long and is throwing that error. Yeah sorry Stacy I saw your comment in code after I posted that question- saw it now.

Comment: break on that line, and look at the members of that list- One or more of them will be less than 8 char long. You might be able to modify it to be something like `ithoutExtension(m).Where(m.length > 7).ToUpper()` but that syntax is off- I don't know the proper from off-the-hip; someone else might know it better

Comment: @alykins `Error 1 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Yeah, my syntax on that is WAY off- I'm dangerous at best with LINQ- It's something worth looking into (I think anyways) and there are some real slick LINQ query writers here. You will have to play with it for a bit and then maybe get someone to help work out kinks.

Comment: @alykins i should give some thing like `(minus) of start`.. but i dont know...  can nu help me out

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. What you really want to know is how to modify that LINQ query to exclude any filenames that are less than 8 characters long. That will eliminate this error. Moreover though the design is flawed- You shouldn't be assuming a file name is any length.

Comment: Please read the answer provided below- it is not the same approach I was suggesting but it will work- I think the LINQ is confusing you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the filename in the path you're using is under 8 characters and so the call to Substring (0,8) is failing.

You need to check the length of your filenames before calling substring on them. Assuming that for filenames under 8 characters you just want the whole filename, you can do something like:

```
var charactersToRead = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(m).length < 8 ? Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(m).length : 8
```

and then change your method calls along the lines of `Substring(0, charactersToRead)`